# Using `rotate()` in css to make chat messages grow upwards in a chat app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I'm building a chat app and I want the new message appear at the very bottom while older messages should appear on top of the new message. I'm new to CSS so I found this [example](https://codepen.io/muratcorlu/pen/KzmQEP) on the Internet which uses `transform` and `direction` CSS properties by rotating `chatArea` container in righthand direction while rotating the messages in the lefthand direction.

While this works this seems to be overkill to me, and is hard to maintain because the orientation of these elements is now "upside down". For example, because `chatArea` div was rotated now in order to set `border-top` CSS property I actually need to set `border-bottom` property.

So I was wondering if there's a simpler solution. Now currently I'm prepending the new message to the old messages using `jQuery` and I tried a lot of combinations with `prepend/append/prependTo` and this is the only one working but I'm not sure which combination of pre-/appending plus simpler CSS would work.

This is `jQuery` code to do prepend:

```
let $messages = jQuery('.messages');
    let $message = jQuery('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');
    $message.append('<p><strong>' + message.name + ' ' + tm + '</strong></p>');
    $message.append('<p>' + message.text + '</p>');
    $message.hide().fadeIn(FADE_TIME);
    $message.prependTo($messages);
```

this is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Socket.IO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap4.1.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="conversation" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 card">
                    <a href="./index.html">Change Settings</a>
                    <h1 class="room-title text-center"></h1>
                        <div class="chatArea">
                            <ul class="messages list-group">
                                <!-- Messages end up here! -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <form id="message-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                            <button type="button" id="showUsersButton" class="btn btn-info">Show room users</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/moment-2.22.1.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="js/queryParams.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS to achieve the rotation:

```
.messages p {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    direction: ltr;
}

.chatArea {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    direction: rtl;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by grow upwards? If you have problem adding new text at the end a simple append() should work

Comment: @user1435897 I meant that the new message should be below older messages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that...no javascript or transforms required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* magic */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

p {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="message">Message6</p>
  <p class="message">Message5</p>
  <p class="message">Message4</p>
  <p class="message">Message3</p>
  <p class="message">Message2</p>
  <p class="message">Message1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It was my first instinct, and you probably not need to reverse the order (I assume new messages will be appended to the bottom). But I think that the thing OP is looking for is the scroll position. It should be locked in the bottom, this only can be achieved  with js

Comment: I assumed that newer responses would be at the top but the basic logic is sound I think.